# TypeScript definition for StoreEnhancer prevents rest parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I’m setting up an app with React-Redux and configured the store, similar to the guide shown [here](https://redux.js.org/recipes/configuringyourstore)

Here is my code:

```
import { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from 'redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from '../reducers/reducers'

export default function configureStore() {

  const middlewares = [thunkMiddleware];
  const middlewareEnhancer = applyMiddleware(...middlewares);

  const enhancers = [middlewareEnhancer];

  const composedEnhancers = compose(...enhancers);

  const preloadedState = (<any>window).__PRELOADED_STATE__;

  delete (<any>window).__PRELOADED_STATE__;

  const store = createStore(rootReducer, preloadedState, composedEnhancers);

  return store;

}
```

However, I keep receiving the following Typescript error when I run build

```
TS2345: Argument of type '(...args: any[]) => {}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'StoreEnhancer<{}, {}>'.
```

I’m confused. Doesn’t Redux’s declaration file state (shown below) that the StoreEnhancer simply receives the Store and State extensions as empty plain objects?

```
export type StoreEnhancer<Ext = {}, StateExt = {}> = (next: StoreEnhancerStoreCreator) => StoreEnhancerStoreCreator<Ext, StateExt>
```

If so, why wouldn’t it accept 'Any' type from the rest parameters, even though I set “noImplicitAny” property to "true" in the config file, as shown below?

(To the best of my knowledge, rest parameters can’t receive a declared type anyway.)

What am I missing?




Also, I’m using the following package versions:

> "react": "^16.4.2",
>   "redux": "^4.0.0",
>   "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
>   "webpack": "^4.16.5",
>   "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.0",
>   "typescript": "^3.0.3"
>   "@types/react": "^16.4.12",
>   "@types/redux": "^3.6.0",
>   "@types/redux-thunk": "^2.1.0"

with the following TS config settings:

> "compilerOptions": {
>      * "outDir": "./dist/",
>      * "sourceMap": true,
>      * "noImplicitAny": true,
>      * "module": "esnext",
>      * "target": "esnext",
>      * "jsx": "react",
>      * "moduleResolution": "node",
>      * "noUnusedLocals": true,
>      * "noUnusedParameters": true,
>      * "strict": true,
>      * "esModuleInterop": false,
>      * "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
>      * "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
>   }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the return type of `composedEnhancers` is `{}`, while `createStore` expects it to be `StoreEnhancerStoreCreator<{}, {}>`.  And that return type of `{}` is coming from your call to `compose`, which is matching this overload in the [type declarations](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/e63c36a4185d1a31d8b7abcba974016fc984b306/index.d.ts#L467) because you are spreading an array of enhancers:

```
export function compose<R>(...funcs: Function[]): (...args: any[]) => R;
```

If you don't specify `R`, it defaults to `{}`.  So either specify `R` or just use `compose(middlewareEnhancer)` unless you really need a dynamic array of enhancers.

Comment: Thanks. It makes, I think. So basically, if I use rest parameters to represent one argument, it causes generic <R> in `compose` to default to exactly one `{}` type, while the spread syntax forces `createStore` to expect more than one `{}` type from `compose`?

Comment: If you pass a single spread argument to `compose`, then the return type of the composed function defaults to `{}`, regardless of the actual number of elements in the spread argument.  The `{}` does not match `StoreEnhancerStoreCreator<Ext, StateExt>`, which is the expected return type of the function passed as the third argument to `createStore`.  There is no spreading going on in `createStore`.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said _...more than one {} type as a result of compose_ instead of _...from compose_. Nonetheless, both alternatives worked. Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, I still don't understand what you're referring to by "more than one {} type".  The expected type is `StoreEnhancerStoreCreator<{}, {}>`.  That has more than one `{}` in it as a type argument, but it's a single type.